# galleria for WordPress not working properly on Mobile devices (responsive)?

Tags: plugins

I am using galleria.io plugin for WordPress to create photo gallery, it works fine and is perfect for my requirement, the only issue is that it creates a huge space between the image and thumbnail when seen on mobile devices - (responsiveness not working) due to the fact that it takes fixed width.
I did try working out with @media css but its not the best solution - i hope someone out there has some JS to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a css or jquery question... but not a wordpress question as you can solve it without the need of wordpress functionality. You have also not provided any code.

Comment: Its a WordPress plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/photo-galleria/
So instead of me trying to hack and fiddle with CSS/Jquery to fix the issue i would have loved to have a solution directly inside the plugin as this should be managed by plugin or may be addon function can be created to automatically take care of this -

Comment: Changing css is not hacking. A developer can only check responsive states for so many browsers. Responsive issues are nornal. But if you don't want to mess with it, then you better off contacting the people who made the plugin.

Comment: i would be ok if it would do default basic responsiveness, and i have done css modification but i was looking for a better hook or addon to make it work through the plugin instead of my css modification and yes i did wrote to them as well but thy never responded so was looking for if someone has experience with this plugin and may know how to go about it